# I accidentally deleted the settings manager

Tags: package-management, settings

Last time i played around with java on my laptop, and i accidentally removed the settings manager ( power settings, screen settings, and so on ) as well.
So i did reinstall java, and i tried to find the package name on the internet without success. Whats the package name of this?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean gnome settings manager?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean Gnome Control Center.

To install:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```